# How do I correctly wrap sum(quantity) = max(sum(quantities)) in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm wanting to take the sum of each unique attribute, then take the maximum of those values. Any advice on how to do this using mySQL? I keep getting an "invalid use of group function".

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| matchName   | varchar(26) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| winner      | varchar(26) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| loser       | varchar(26) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| winningGame | varchar(26) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dateofWin   | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| matchName  | varchar(26) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| date       | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| grandPrize | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| location   | varchar(26) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state      | varchar(26) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| attendance | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The closest I've gotten so far was by using:

```
select Results.winner, Tourney.grandPrize 
from Tourney 
inner join Results 
on Results.matchName=Tourney.matchName;
```

Comment: show us some code and data

Comment: As @A.D. mentioned, we need a minimum reproducible example to be able to help you. But just based on your title, it looks like you're trying to assign a sum to to something else, which isn't valid (or logical, really). You can assign something to a summary but you can't assign a summary to something.

Comment: :-) so where is quantity? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear,

I've upvoted @A.D. comment, you should provide more details, table structure, data sample, expected result, current query that brings error etc..

But quick answer for your question is:

```
SELECT t.*, MAX(t.sum_qty) as max_qty
FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(qty) as sum_qty
  FROM test
  GROUP BY order_id // you can set any group field you need here
) AS t
```